# Safe to delete graphs.db?

Tags: node.js, nsolid

I have an instance of NSolid console running and graphs.db directory is chewing up a lot of space. Is it safe to delete that periodically? The UI only shows data for 15 seconds, it doesn't seem like storing all of that data is particularly useful

Answer (score 2):

The safe way is stopping N|Solid Console and then delete the file.
If you are not interested on keep old data you are safe to delete it.